# How to use Excel Web App Data Connections to fetch data from a Rest API?

Tags: excel, ms-office, office365

What are the methods/best practices by which i would be able to populate data in an excel web app using REST API Query?

I would like to create and upload a template to my website which would refresh the data shown by querying REST or SOAP based services.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Hi, well i've tried out the web app and their javascript api, i know how to manually process data and feed it to the excel sheet. 

What i would like to know is if it's possible to use the data-connections feature already present there somehow in tandem with excel templates in order to avoid writing the javascript. So that when i hit refresh, data is recalculated after being fetched from our API.

Comment: I've searched high and low for documentation on how i might do this for no avail, i've tried the MSDN forum with no success, now i'm hoping i might find someone with expertise here who can atleast give me a sign as to whether such a thing is even possible.

P.S> i liked your link :)

Comment: my overall programming knowledge is 4 months of basic VBA coding so far, so hardly ever I could help you. Try to provide code samples or at least possible approaches by modifying your post - that will attract more experienced answerers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about a normal jquery based webapp using wcf service to populate your excel. So simply put initiates an ajax call to your REST endpoint?

```
try{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/REST-URL',
        contentType: 'xml',
        data: '{data : your data does in here}',
        success: function (msg) {
            Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(msg);
        },
        error: function () {
            result = "fail";
        }
    });
} catch (err) {
    result = err.description;
}
```

Best practices should be based on how complicated your app is.